# Accidentally delete .XIB file from XCODE

Tags: objective-c, xcode6

I was accidentally delete .XIB file from my project.It contain all my main designs. Is it possible to recover it?

Comment: If you don't have a backup and did not use version tracking, it is likely not possible to recover it. Try checking the Trash or try a data recovery software of some kind. Consider using version tracking (Git, svn etc.) in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have removed the file from only your project ,it will be available in the Trash